# Match two or more files using Glob

Tags: glob

I'm trying to figure out how to match two or more files using this [Glob Online Tester](https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/pen/OXQjrZ).

What would be the expression to match **styles/main.css** and **index.html** files?

```
images/icons/home.svg
images/icons/phone.svg
images/promo.gif
images/logo.png
styles/main.css
index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just

```
styles/main.css
index.html
```

As seen here:

[image: screenshot of patterns in action]

---

Alternatively you could [read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multimatch#globbing-patterns):

> - `{}` allows for a comma-separated list of "or" expressions

... and use this:

```
{styles/main.css,index.html}
```

Comment: It's two different expressions. Each line is evaluated as a single expression. I need something that would look like `?(styles/main.css | index.html)`